# 'transitionConfig' is removed in favor of the new animation APIs

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-stack

I am working with a react native application, and it shows a warning in the console

```
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
import {fromRight} from 'react-navigation-transitions';
const ApplyNowNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home,
    Profile,
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    transitionConfig: () => fromRight(),
  }
);
```

> WARN  Deprecation in 'createStackNavigator':
>
> transitionConfig' is removed in favor of the new animation APIs

Is there any solution to fix this issue?

Comment: try using react-navigation-stack 1.10.3

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to update your code to use to use the new Animation API: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/stack-navigator.html#animations

From the code you posted, you can change it to the following instead to have a slide from right animation:

```js
import { createStackNavigator, TransitionPresets } from 'react-navigation-stack';

const ApplyNowNav = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Home,
    Profile,
  },
  {
    headerMode: 'none',
    defaultNavigationOptions: {
      ...TransitionPresets.SlideFromRightIOS,
    },
  }
);
```

Comment: I want to have different transition base on route name how can I achieve it with this new api

Comment: react navigation 4

Comment: How can i customize my transitions and pass like above?

Answer (score 1):

1. Update react-navigation and use creatStackNavigator component instead of StackNavigator.
2. Check current methods and syntax, there is a lot of changes compare to previous syntax.

Works for me when I updated the code